# Is this type of query safe from sql injection?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-injection, node-postgres, prepared-statement

let tableName = req.body.tableName

let colName = req.body.col1+","+req.body.col2

sqlString = `INSERT INTO ${tableName}(${colName}) VALUES ($1,$2) RETURNING *`

Comment: No, absolutely not. What makes you think it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you are using user's input as is inside a SQL query.

Use some kind of query builder like [knex](http://knexjs.org/), which has a built in way of escaping user's input properly.